# Return to normal mode without leaving the home row

Tags: vim, key, mode

I've been trying out [vim](http://www.vim.org/), and the emphasis on speed and accessibility makes sense for the veteran programmer. I've previously used [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), and currently use a combination of [nano](http://www.nano-editor.org/), and stuff like [gedit](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/) or [geany](http://www.geany.org/).

I'm confused by the need to constantly switch modes, and that returning from insert mode to normal mode requires leaving the home row to press <kbd>Esc</kbd>. I've read that previously, this key was <kbd>Tab</kbd> on some systems where vim was first used, which makes a lot more sense, but not on current systems where tab is expected to participate in smart indenting when coding.

Returning to normal mode is an operation that you need to perform all the time. Is there some alternative key mapping that makes this quicker, or mappings that I simply don't know about that do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also use ^[. If you've mapped your caps lock key to control (highly recommended), this becomes a rather easy keystroke.

Comment: I've heard of vi users who remap CapsLk to Esc, but this is what I do. +1  Additionally, ^C exits to normal mode, but has other effects.

Comment: Personally I also like ^[ with caps lock remapped to ctrl. For other ideas, including remapping jj to <esc>, see this this page: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key

Answer (score 13):

Ctrl+C also return you to normal mode

Answer (score 3):

You can map whatever you like to escape:

```
imap kj <Esc>
```

I haven't yet run across a situation where I need to type kj next to each other, besides when I talk about this mapping.  I've seen other people use jk or jj, but kj works best for me.

Comment: *I* haven't yet... :)  That said, just wait a second between the two and the mapping won't take effect.

Answer (score 3):

I personally use the `Capslock` key as the second `Esc` key, so it is very comfortable. You can do it by adding the following lines to your `.xmodmap` file:

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Escape
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally use `ii` to get out of insert mode while staying on the home row, but it is only a matter of personal preference:

`inoremap ii <Esc>`

`i` to go *in* insert and `ii` to go *out*. This is easy for your finger to remember. (I tend to still use `<Esc>` though)

Answer (score 0):

I personally use Left Control as escape and Caps Lock as Left Control. It is not vim mapping, but some xmodmap+setxkbmap magic:

```
! ~/.Xmodmap
! Control_R
keycode 37 = Escape
```

and `ctrl:nocaps` in X keyboard options. You may have different keycode though.

Answer (score 0):

[**Use Alt/Meta In a Terminal**](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key#Use_Alt.2FMeta_In_a_Terminal)

> If you use Vim in a terminal, simply press alt/meta+normal_mode_key. Most terminals send an escape character followed by the normal_mode_key that you pressed, removing the need to press escape yourself.
>
> The terminals konsole and gnome terminal send the escape by default when you press alt/meta+normal_mode_key. For Xterm you can ctrl+click and select the option "Meta sends escape" or "Alt sends escape".
>
> Thus in insert mode pressing alt+h alt+j alt+k alt+l all take you to normal mode and move in the expected direction. You can hold down alt when moving even while in normal mode since the additional ESC that is sent does no harm.
>
> The advantage of using this scheme is that you can use the alt/meta+key combination with any normal mode key, e.g.

```
Alt+o opens a new line below the one you are currently editing,
Alt+A appends to the end of the current line,
Alt+p pastes at the current insert location.
Alt+k moves up
```

> Thus using vim via a terminal gives you these short cut powers on any stock standard system without the need to edit each systems vim mappings.